# Angular TypeError: "provider.ngAfterViewInit is not a function at callProviderLifecycles"

Tags: angular

I get the error

> evt = TypeError: provider.ngAfterViewInit is not a function at callProviderLifecycles

in my Angular project. The mysterious thing is that not only do I not have an `ngAfterViewInit` method but I also don't have the corresponding `implements` clause.

The even odder thing is that I undo my file back to a previous state and it starts working again.

Answer (score 8):

It seems that something in the CLI caches which methods existed at some point in time.

I am using `ng serve --source-map=false --aot --live-reload=false`

Restarting `ng serve` cleared out whatever was caching this.

Comment: Indeed, restarting without any other change, solves it. The old IT joke.